# Too much gin in potato-scallion soup

Tags: soup

I made this recipe for Scallion Soup but made substitutions for what I had - beef stock instead of chicken, and coconut milk instead of cream.  I added gin because I saw a similar recipe that called for dry sherry... but I think I added way too much.  (Also, I think I cooked it too long because I can barely taste the scallions any longer!  Although I just followed the times in the recipe.)

I also added sweet potato, another ingredient that pretty much just tastes like mush.

Any ideas on how to make this soup better?  It's pretty bland other than the gin taste.

http://www.saveur.com/article/Recipes/Scallion-Soup

Comment: Even without the substitutions, this soup is supposed to be bland. A vichysoisse and relatives generally have a subtle aroma.

Comment: After all the substitutions, I think it is fair to say this soup is more "inspired by" that recipe....

Answer (score 2):

You have cream of beefy gin soup, with no scallion taste?  Unless you are desperate not to lose the ingredients, it might be time to let this one go the way of all things.

If you really wish to recover it, and are willing to risk more good ingredients, I would get some chuck, and braise it with onions, then add it to the soup.  Finish with fresh scallions, perhaps lightly sauteed.  This would give you strongly flavored meat to compete with the gin, akin to venison and juniper.  Also, hot sauce :-)

But it may not be worth it... you could braise the beef with the onions, and then just eat it!

Comment: Cream of beefy gin soup is about right :)  Thanks for the suggestion!  I agree it's a risk.  Do you happen to know what I did wrong to lose the scallions?  I suppose if I try again - just cook it for a shorter amount of time?

Comment: @Elizabeth: Somewhat of a guess, but a lot of the volatile flavour compounds in onions, garlic, hot peppers, etc. are alcohol soluble, and gin has 3-4x the amount of alcohol that normal wine does. It sounds like you just basically overpowered everything with alcohol.